# I always have some doubts regarding the inequalities in cases where the function become Complex in the field for the real numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, logarithms

Consider this inequality $x + \log\left(x \right)> \log\left (x\right) - 2$
Does this inequality has $-1$ as its solution ?
It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: $-1$ is not in the domain of $\log(x)$... and if you take $\log(-1)$ you get complex numbers (which cannot be ordered).  Why not just subtract the $\log(x)$ from both sides and conclude that $x>-2$ satisfies the inequality (and $x>0$ is the domain)... so the inequality is true for all $x>0$.

Comment: @TravisJ .For me that seems to be the answer. But according to Wolfram Alpha [link]http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x+%2B+log%28x%29+%3E+-2+%2B+log%28x%29%29

Comment: Wolfram alpha subtracted the $\log(x)$ from both sides... then forgot that your inequality only makes sense when $x>0$.  The same sort of thing happens if you cancel fractions and say $\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}=x+1$... the equals is true, provided that $x\neq 1$.  There's a hidden domain issue that wolframalpha seems to neglect.

Comment: @TravisJ . The problems does not occur with any of the equalities on Wolfram.com as far as i have seen. But it occurs for this particular inequalities that too with only this type. Even it gives the correct solution for the inequalities like   x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2} - 4} > 3 + \frac{1}{x^{2} - 4}  . [link]http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x**2+%2B+1%2F%28x**2-4%29+%3E+3+%2B+1%2F%28x**2-4%29%29  which is a correct solution. Problem occurs only with this involving the Log(x) function.

Comment: Bare with me, if the way i am writing comments is too messed up. I have not used stackexchange too often for asking questions.

Comment: It's possible that points not in the domain of the fraction inequality were outside of the solution set (so there was no inconsistency).  The link seems a little broken, so I can't follow it to see exactly what you had... but that's my guess.  Assuming you're not working with imaginary numbers then the correct solution to the problem you originally posed is $x>0$.

Comment: Actually, if I read the fraction inequality right, the solution should be all $x>\sqrt{3}$ or $x<-\sqrt{3}$ provided that $x\neq \pm 2$.

Comment: Btw, if you write \$x^{2}\$ it will render as $x^{2}$... i.e. put dollar signs around all your "math" content.

Comment: I believe that if you allow complex numbers you may get a solution for the negative values. May be that's why Wolfram  allows negative values for log function.

Comment: @Moti what are you thoughts on the inequality $x^{2}$ + $x$ < -3 . Does this inequality possess any solutions ?

Comment: @gxyd Try graphing $x^2 + x + 3 = O$ and then shade on the appropriate side if the graph.

Comment: If you allow complex numbers (a + ib) you could get solutions along the real axis that will result from complex values of x that will result values as desired. If you require that the result will be purely real, it requires more investigation. You have a solution to the above equation: $$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-11}}{2}$$